# what if I ask my husband that I don't want to stay with my in-laws as he is abroad? can I go and stay with my mother?

Tags: husband-wife, family

Its been about 4 months for our marriage. I am staying with my In-laws, I am not allow to go outside with my father-in-laws permission not even to my mothers place and do anything. He verbally abuse me for being incapable for their son and I don't know how to read Quran properly, that I am a liar and good for nothing. He makes me feel bad about my self because of that I am losing my self confidence and self esteem. He tells he is always right and scold me for no reason. If I open my mouth he catches words and abuse me for that. he says bad about my family and me. Nobody is there to support me in front of him because their are scared of him. He always makes me feel awful and threatens me that he will ask his son to give me divorce. I am not allowed speak with my husband freely. I fear scared and depressed about all this but can't tell anyone, is not haram to stay in my mothers house till I get my visa. He calls me with different names and says I am mentally retreated. He doesn't my future children to be like me. Can In-laws abuse you?

Comment: ... not an answer on Islam, but: just take your things and go to your mother.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Your in-laws have no right to order you any thing. You shouldn't have accepted to move in their house in first place. Whether you stay or not in their house is your decision and even your husband couldn't order you this. IMHO he shouldn't have married you if he is unable to be in charge of you and give you accommodation.